# Первое приложение под Android

Tags: android, eclipse

Установил IDE, поставил ADT и SDK. При попытке вывести hello world - ничего не выводится. Не пойму в чем дело.

В string.xml все правильно написано. А при компиляции грусть.
[image]

> [2012-04-02 22:31:23 - ddms] Could not open Selected VM debug port (8700). Make sure you do not have another instance of DDMS or of the eclipse plugin running. If it's being used by something else, choose a new port number in the preferences.
>
> [2012-04-02 22:32:06 - ddms] Can't bind to local 8600 for debugger
>
> [2012-04-02 22:32:09 - ddms] Can't bind to local 8601 for debugger
>
> [2012-04-02 22:32:10 - ddms] Can't bind to local 8601 for debugger
>
> [2012-04-02 22:32:10 - ddms] Can't bind to local 8602 for debugger

Comment: Хотя бы логи покажите.

Comment: Добавлено в вопрос.

Comment: Исходники, исходники нужно показывать!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас отладчик не может подцепиться к приложению. Либо запущены 2 инстанса DDMS/ADB или глушит файрволл с антивирусом. Перезагрузите и остановите антивирус с файрволлом.

А еще лучше запустите приложение без отладчика.

Answer (score 0):

Советую поставить TEGRA ANDROID DEVELOPMENT PACK - в нём все что нужно для разработки, а главное отлично настроено. Проблем типа этой не будет =)